# Issue with python 3.0 pexpect module

Tags: python, function, if-statement, python-3.4, pexpect

Here is the piece of base code which I wrote to do an automatic ssh to the linux, but every time it is getting into cases==0, which means it's thinking every time it's a "newkey"/ (yes/no):

Please help me solving it. I am stuck at the basic level.

```
#!/home/python/Python-3.4.3/python

import subprocess;
import pexpect;


def f1_input():
        global server, id, password, commands;
        server = input("Enter Server: ");
        id = input("Enter User ID: ");
        password = input("Enter Password: ");
        commands = input("Enter Commands: ");
        return server, id, password, commands;


def f2_exec():
        child = pexpect.spawn('ssh %s@%s %s'%(id,server,commands));
        newkey = 'Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? ';
        passkey = 'password:';
        cases = child.expect([newkey, passkey, pexpect.EOF]);
        print("cases=", cases);

        if cases==0:
                print("cases=", cases);
                child.sendline('yes');
                child.expect('password:');
                child.sendline(password);
                child.expect(pexpect.EOF);
                print(child.before);

        elif cases==1:
                print("cases=", cases);
                child.sendline(password);
                child.expect(pexpect.EOF);
                print(child.before);

        elif cases==2:
                print("cases=", cases);
                print("Timeout!!!");

        else:
                print("cases=", cases);
                print("EXIT");

f1_input();
f2_exec();
```

Comment: Well, you shouldn't `global` and `return` a variable at onetime.

Comment: Reimplement your problem in 3 lines of code. It'll help you.

Comment: Okay, that I can change. I will remove "global". Yeah that makes sense.

Comment: Well, but the second comment: reimplementing in 3 lines of code, not sure how it is possible, as the conditions will have to be there.

Comment: why do you think it is `pexpect` issue? Have you tried to run the same command from the command-line manually? Do you see the newkey message?

Comment: The code with input and the cases don't add to the question. Write a new script, with 3 lines and hard coded values: `child = pexpect.spawn...`, `cases = child.expect...`, and `print(cases)`. Strip the problem down to its essence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is with ssh, and should reproduce without pexpect. It may not be able to write to ~/.ssh/known_hosts file, or option StrictHostKeyChecking=no in ~/.ssh/config or similar.

Furthermore, your solution is better resolved with a program such as sshpass(1) or a python module like paramiko.